# Cannot get list of events for Calendar API v3 from another Gmail account

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use Google Calendar API v3 to retrieve list of events from another Google account (not from a logged user in my machine). 
Only list of events that I get is from logged user in my machine, even if I try to 'fill' user account email.
What should I be supposed to do?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package us.com.manga;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;

import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author robert bones
 */
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {





    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME
            = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";

    /**
     * Directory to store user credentials for this application.
     */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/calendar-java-quickstart");

    /**
     * Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}.
     */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /**
     * Global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY
            = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES
            = Arrays.asList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public  Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        //InputStream in
        //        = NewServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        InputStream in = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().
                getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets
                = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow
                = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                        .setClientId("xxxx@gmail.com")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("xxxxx@gmail.com");

        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Calendar client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized Calendar client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public  com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar
            getCalendarService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
//Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
        //  .setApplicationName("applicationName").build();
// Iterate over the events in the specified calendar
        String pageToken = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
         try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
                    /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
                    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                    out.println("<html>");
                    out.println("<head>");
                    out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");
                    out.println("</head>");
                    out.println("<body>");

                    do {
            Events events = getCalendarService().events().list("primary").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            List<Event> items = events.getItems();
            for (Event event : items) {


                    out.println("<h1>" + event.getSummary() + "</h1>");

                }


            pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
        } while (pageToken != null);

                    out.println("</body>");
                    out.println("</html>");
         }

    }



}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the user you login with have rights to see the other user's calendar?

Comment: @JimGarrison No, user I do login does not know/see anything regarding these another user calendars.

Comment: Then why would you expect this to work?

Answer (score 0):

When you authenticate it gives your application access to all of the information that the user who authenticated has access to.

**Example:**

If I authenticate your application you will have access to read my Google Calendars.  As well as any public calendars like holidays in the USA.  (The latter is public data you don't need to be authenticated to access it)

My authenticating your application will not give you or me access to Jon Snows google calendar account that is his private data.

**Answer:**

You only have access to the data that the authenticated user has access to.   Not someone else's data.

**What should you do**

Ask the other user to give the user you are authenticating with access to their calendar.